# Create PersistentVolume using diskName and diskURI

Tags: azure, kubernetes

In Kubernetes (Azure AKS), how do I create a `PersistentVolume` resource that is bound to my own managed disk Azure resource that has a specific `diskName` and `diskURI` (resource id)?

Here is one example but for a Pod:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mypodrestored
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myfrontendrestored
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/mnt/azure"
        name: volume
  volumes:
    - name: volume
      azureDisk:
        kind: Managed
        diskName: pvcRestored
        diskURI: /subscriptions/<guid>/resourceGroups/MC_myResourceGroupAKS_myAKSCluster_eastus/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/pvcRestored
```

Comment: Is your question about how to do it through the Azure API or the Azure UI?

Comment: It's about how to author the actual yaml. Then execute it using kubectl create -f pv.yml

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own managed disk in the AKS cluster and then attach it to the pod which you need. For more details about the steps, see [Volumes with Azure disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-volume).

The result will like this:

[image]